# send multiple requests with Token authentication?

Tags: python, pandas, api, dataframe, python-requests

Currently my API requires to use Token authentication.

```
POST /api/authorize HTTP/1.1

"version": "20151130", // The version of the REST API you are using
"client_id": "01234567890123456789", // Your 20 char public client id
"client_secret": "0123456789..." // Your 40 char client secret
```

I get the response:

```
{
  "auth_token": "abcdef...",
  "auth_expires": "20180524T062442Z"
}
```

My current pattern is like this:

I have a list of `items` I need to pass to the API via POST method.
This is my main function: `ProcessProducts` which receives a Pandas Dataframe which includes a product per row.

```
def ProcessProducts(products):
   all_results = []
   for _, product in products.iterrows():
     results = GetProductData(product)
     if results:
        all_results.extend(results)
   return all_results


def GetAuthorizationToken():
    payload = {
        'version': api_version,
        'client_id': api_client_id,
        'client_secret': api_client_secret
    }

    request_url = '%s%s' % (api_host, '/api/authorize')
    r = requests.post(request_url, data=payload)

    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception('Failed to authorize: ' + r.text)

    token_data = json.loads(r.text)
    api_auth_token = token_data['auth_token']
    api_auth_expires = token_data['auth_expires']

    return {
        "X-API-Version": api_version,
        "Authorization": "token %s" % api_auth_token
    }
```

Client function...

```
def GetProductData(self, product):
    """Gets Product information from API."""

    url = '%s%s' % (self.api_url, _COMPANY_DATA)
    request = json.dumps({'products': [product]})
    form_data = {'request': request, 'start': 1, 'limit': 1000}
    logging.info('Looking up: %s', url)
    auth_headers = GetAuthorizationToken()
    response = _SendApiRequest(url, auth_headers, form_data)
    return _HandleResponse(response)


def _SendApiRequest(self, url, auth_headers, form_data):
    session = requests.Session()
    try:
      response = session.post(
          url,
          timeout=(_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, _READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS),
          headers=auth_headers,
          data=form_data,
          verify=True)  # Check for valid public/signed HTTPS certificate.
      response.raise_for_status()
      return response
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
      logging.exception(err)
```

Questions:

- API returns the code expiry field "auth_expires", Where may be the best way to check in code when token expires so I can request a new one?
- Is there a better Pattern to call API, so I can control the QPS rate as well (Use RateLimiter). Right now I'm creating a Session per request, which may not be ideal.

Comment: Isn't the server supposed to send the token expiry along with the token? That's how token auth is supposed to be done I think.

Comment: Yes. that's correct I think my question is where may be the best place to check for expiration. Let me edit for clarification.

Comment: Depends on what type of token method you are using. You get your expiration in the `auth_expires` field, when you return it from the server you want that value represented in one of the headers. You can use whatever you want, so for example `return {
        "X-API-Version": api_version,
        "Authorization": "token %s" % api_auth_token,
        "Token-expiration": api_auth_expires
    }` but there are standard ones for the token methods out there.